# AVG function returns wrong average

Tags: sql-server-2008, functions

I have a simple table with a column of type REAL.

There are 2 rows in the table and the values are 0.23 and 0.24. If I run the following:

```
SELECT AVG(MyColumn) FROM dbo.MyTable
```

I would expect to get a result of 0.235 but actually I get 0.2349999901234.

Can somebody please tell me why?

Answer (score 9):

Stop using REAL and use DECIMAL instead. REAL and FLOAT are approximate data types and can't represent all numbers in the nice, rounded way you are used to. Compare these:

```
DECLARE @a REAL = 0.23, @b REAL = 0.24;
SELECT AVG(r) FROM (SELECT r = @a UNION SELECT r = @b) AS x;
```

Result:

```
0.234999999403954
```

Now using DECIMAL instead:

```
DECLARE @a DECIMAL(10,4) = 0.23, @b DECIMAL(10,4) = 0.24;
SELECT AVG(r) FROM (SELECT r = @a UNION SELECT r = @b) AS x;
```

Result:

```
0.235000
```

Some related reading:

- http://web.archive.org/web/20130205023610/http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-does-3-2-1-5-4-7000000000000002.html
- http://web.archive.org/web/20120208202619/http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-datatype-should-i-use-for-numeric-columns.html
- https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

[Decimal is not perfect, either; you can lose precision if you need more decimal places than supported, for example](https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2007/10/so-called-exact-numerics-are-not-at-all-exact/). But for most applications this is not an issue.

Comment: Here is a slightly more nerdy explanation of what is going on behind the scenes when you choose Floating-Point Arithmetic http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Google will reveal more related pages and pdfs: **[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://www.google.com/search?q=What+Every+Computer+Scientist+Should+Know+About+Floating-Point+Arithmetic)**

Answer (score 2):

REAL and FLOAT are approximate data types.

FROM: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx

"Approximate-number data types for use with floating point numeric data. Floating point data is approximate; therefore, **not all values in the data type range** can be represented exactly."